# How to sort by row from terminal

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing

I was looking at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163358/how-to-sort-lines-in-a-text-file-from-the-terminal)  and I wondered if the following could be done from terminal. I did it in python, just want to see if it could be done from terminal, bash scripting or whatever.

Suppose I have a file that looks like so:

```
2,4,5,14,9
40,3,5,10,1
```

could it be sorted like so, by rows (lines)

```
2,4,5,9,14
1,3,5,10,40
```

or is it too complicated? I did it using python, I just want to know if it could be done so next time I might not use python. What I have done, is creating lists and sorting them.

Comment: I asked it here because I saw the other question, if it should not be asked here feel free to close it or delete it

Comment: I added the missing comma between `5` and `14` in your input example. Based on your output, I assume that was a typo, please clarify if it was not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another Perl approach:

```
perl -F, -lane 'print join ",",sort {$a<=>$b} @F' file.txt
```

And another shell/coreutils one (though personally, I prefer steeldriver's [excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/447485/85695) which uses the same idea):

```
while read line; do 
    tr , $'\n' < <(printf -- "%s" "$line") | sort -g | tr $'\n' , | sed 's/,$/\n/';
done < file.txt
```

Comment: Nice solution, I up-vote immediately

Comment: As is yours and as did I :)

Comment: I hate it when I receive too many good answers :) and when you have to pick one randomly, it's like asking myself "what do I like more, chocolate bars or icecream?"

Answer (score 7):

This should do about what you're looking for.  It will read a file (test.txt) and create an output file (sorted.txt) with the sorted lines in the same order as they appear in the original file.

```
while read line; do j=$(echo "$line" | sed -e 's/,/\n/g' | sort -n); echo "$j" 
    | sed -e 's/ /,/g' >> sorted.txt; done < test.txt
```

Comment: did you note the space in the first line `2,4,5 14,9`?

Comment: bad usage of cat! To operate on each line, do `while read line; do ...; done < test.txt`

Comment: @FredrikPhil: Thank you.  I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The only real difficulty in doing what you want using command-line scripting is that the available `sort` function expects to sort *lines within a file*, rather than *fields within a line*. To work around that, you could replace the field delimiters, line-by-line, with newlines prior to the `sort` function, then replace the newlines with delimiters again in each line after sorting.

There are a number of available text processing utilities which would allow you to do that (including `sed`, `awk`, or even the simple `tr`) however the bash shell itself can do a lot nowadays. Assuming you meant for the input to be comma-delimited (you have a mix of commas and whitespace delimiters in your example) you could do:

```
while read line; do 
  sorted=$(sort -g -- <<< "${line//,/$'\n'}")
  printf -- "${sorted//$'\n'/,}\n"
done < file
```

If you *do* need to handle space delimiters in the input, then you can add them as part of a character list `[, ]` for the input substring replacement:

```
while read line; do 
  sorted=$(sort -g -- <<< "${line//[, ]/$'\n'}")
  printf -- "${sorted//$'\n'/,}\n"
done < file
```

(note that the output remains strictly comma-delimited though).

Answer (score 4):

Here comes an `awk` solution,

```
while read -r line; do (echo $line | awk '{ n=split($1,a,","); asort(a); for(i=0;i<=n;i++) { print a[i];}}') | xargs | sed -e 's/ /,/g'; done < text.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- `awk '{ n=split($1,a,","); asort(a); for(i=0;i<=n;i++) { print a[i];}}'`

  awk Splits the field 1 according to the delimiter `,` and store each value into the array `a` finally the top position is stored into the variable `n`. Next `asort(a)` function sort down the array values.Then the for loop inside the awk command prints the sorted values in the format of record by record.
- `xargs | sed -e 's/ /,/g'`

  `xargs` combines all the rows into a single row.
- `sed -e 's/ /,/g'`

  It replaces the spaces with commas `,`
- `while read -r line;`

  All the above `awk`,`xargs`,`sed` functions are done line by line with the help of `while` loop.

Answer (score 3):

## Using tr and sed

Similar in spirit to [what jkt123 wrote](https://askubuntu.com/a/447434/71738):

```
while read i; do tr , \\n <<< $i | sort -n | tr \\n , | sed 's/,$//'; done
```

It iterates over the lines, and for each line replaces commas by newlines, sorts the resulting lines numerically, then turns newlines back to commas. The main problem is that this will end the whole result with a comma not a newline, which is addressed by that last sed. It strips the last comma and also implicitely adds a newline to its output.

## Using bash arrays

Here is a different approach to deal with this “join with commas” issue:

```
while read i; do j=( $(tr , \\n <<< $i | sort -n) ); ( IFS=,; echo "${j[*]}"; ); done
```

Or written with line wraps:

```
while read i
do
   j=( $(tr , \\n <<< $i | sort -n) )
   ( IFS=,; echo "${j[*]}"; )
done
```

It uses a bash array to store the result of the sorted row, and makes use of the way bash expands arrays into string literals using the `IFS` special variable.

Answer (score 3):

`python -c "your code here" input.txt`

Or, if your program has multiple lines and `eval()` is too slow:

`python yourprogram.py input.txt`

This oneliner works:

```py
python -c "for l in open('input.txt'):print(','.join(sorted(l.strip().split(','), key=int)))"
```

Comment: The OP is not looking for a python-based solution.

Comment: Yes he is: "just want to see if it could be done from terminal, bash scripting **or whatever**."

Comment: Lol, you nailed it, then!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily using perl

consider you have file `text.txt`

```
cat text.txt

1,5,7,8,3,6
10,34,67,1,2,0,5
```

Now the following perl code will sort the rows in `text.txt`

```
 perl -i -e 'while(<>){chomp; my @sorted = sort { $a <=> $b } split(",", $_); print join (",", @sorted); print "\n"}' text.txt
```

After sorting

```
cat text.txt

1,3,5,6,7,8
0,1,2,5,10,34,67
```

Comment: You could shorten this significantly with `perl -i -lne 'print join (",", sort {$a <=> $b} split(",", $_));' text.txt`. The `-n` flag is the same as `while(<>){}` and the `-l` adds a `\n` to every print call _and_ also activates implicit `chomp()`.

Answer (score 2):

The <strike>shortest</strike> solution using a perl oneliner:

```
perl -ne 'print join(",", sort { $a <=> $b } split(/,|\n/))."\n"' text.txt
```

Comment: Heh, I'd left my answer open for a while and hadn't seen this, but not the shortest :P

Comment: Je m'incline ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I needed this functionality too, and a solution I found is as follows (assuming data are in test file):

```
cat test | while read line; do echo $(echo $line | datamash -t',' transpose |sort -g| datamash -t',' transpose); done
```