# How to tell which parameter is being supplied to a command with a redirectioin operator?

Tags: command-line, bash

This works:

> $ echo "notify-send HELLO" | at now

This doesn't:

> $ at now < echo "notify-send HELLO"

It says 'file or directory not found".

I understand there's a `-f` option to this command, which with which i can supply the file to be executed at a given moment.

So this got me thinking... in general, how do i know for which parameter the redirection operators supply the value?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean by "which parameter". Your issue is probably that you (mistakenly) think that `foo | bar` and `bar < foo` are equivalent. They are not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are using two different things here and should be using a third. Let's see:

1. `|` : This is the *pipe* operator, it serves to pass the output of one process as input to another:

   ```
   foo | bar
   ```

   This runs the program `foo` and passes its output as input to the program `bar`.
2. `>`,`<`,`>>` and `<<`: These are the [redirection operators](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/redircb.html), they serve to send data to/from *files*:

   - `foo > bar` : runs the program `foo` and saves its output to the *file* `bar`, **overwriting**<sup>1</sup> its contents and creating it if it does not exist.
   - `foo >> bar` : runs the program `foo` and saves its output to the *file* `bar`, **appending** to its contents and creating it if it does not exist.
   - `foo < bar` :  runs `foo`, telling it to read input from the *file* `bar`.
   - The `<<` is a special case, since there is no point in "appending" input to a command,  the `<<` is primarily (exclusively AFAIK) used for [Here Documents](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

     ```
     $ cat << EOF > file.txt
     > Hello World!
     > EOF
     ```

     The construct `<< SomeStringHere > Out.file` will redirect all text written until it encounters the ending string (`EOF` in the example above) to the target file. Here docs allow you to easily format multi-line strings and include variables and special characters.
3. The `<<<` operator, the [Here String](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings), is like a Here Document but it expands variables. So, for example:

   ```
   grep foo <<< "$bar"
   ```

   The command above is equivalent to `echo "$bar" | grep foo`.
4. What you are actually looking for is called [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) and is another way to pass the output of a command to another. It consists of `<(command)`.

   ```
   foo <(bar)
   ```

   So, for your `at` example, you could do

   ```
   at now < <(echo "notify-send HELLO")
   ```

   The above works because process substitution actually creates a file (read the link above for more details) and it is the file descriptor of that file that is passed with `<` to `at now`.

---

<sup>1</sup> The default behavior is to overwrite, this can be modified by setting the `noclobber` option to bash. If set, `echo foo > bar` will fail if `bar` exists. In that case, it can be forced using `echo foo |> bar` instead. See section 3.6.2 [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.htm).

Comment: Nice answer! very thorough (especially including the differences between the file redirectors)

Comment: @steeldriver aww, shucks, thanks :) And so was [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/447485/85695) under appreciated gem. I wish I could have given you a +1 for each of the various pitfalls your solution silently avoids.

Comment: Could you please also expand to include some information about `<<` and `<<<` (which @steeldriver mentioned in his answer). Moreover, are there more - something like `>>>>>>` or `<<<<<<<<<<`?

Comment: @Aditya done. And don't worry, it stops at `<<<` :)

Answer (score 12):

In this case, `echo "notify-send HELLO"` is a *process* not a file - so you need a [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) rather than a file redirection

```
at now < <(echo "notify-send HELLO")
```

You could also have used a [here string](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) to avoid the `echo` command entirely

```
at now <<< "notify-send HELLO"
```

Comment: Having seen the kind of questions you tend to like (same ones I do) I think you should spend some more time over on [unix.se]. We live and die for cool shell tricks over there..

Comment: @terdon: same thing for perl golfers?

Comment: @SylvainPineau oooh yeah. Very much so :). Seriously, the kind of question that you, steeldriver and I enjoy is much more common over there. The place is full of commandline geeks [some](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) [of](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/stephane-chazelas) [whom](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7453/slm) are absurdly knowledgeable.