# Display all the lines which ends with the word “unix” or specific word in terminal

Tags: command-line, files, text-processing

How to display all the lines which ends with the word `unix` in any
given file and sorts those lines in ascending order.

Comment: And http://askubuntu.com/questions/163358/how-to-sort-lines-in-a-text-file-from-the-terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command should be :

```
grep 'unix$' your_file | sort
```

Of course you shoud replace `your_file` with the file you want to sort.

Comment: I would do `sort -d` for dictionary sorting style.